# Where can I go to ask where I can find certain software?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm trying to hunt down a version of Release Manager Update 1, but it looks like questions about where I can find software are against the rules.

Where can I ask where to find software like this?

Comment: Kind of.  It sounds more like they are looking for a recommendation.  I already knew what I wanted, I was looking for a download location.  But I could see it going either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a download of that specific product, you're out of luck. That has no place on Stack Exchange.

If you are looking for software with very specific requirements, then you can go to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

However, they have [very strict requirements for questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). Be sure your request fulfills them. They need to be strict to avoid becoming a spam haven.